# Javascript playing a video - what am i doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-video

I think the code is self-explanatory, the button doesn't work, what am I doing wrong?

Using Chrome.

http://jsbin.com/ugoni3/edit

Comment: Note also that Firefox doesn't support the *H.264/MPEG-4 AVC* video format, it only supports *Ogg Theora*, see: [Media formats supported by the audio and video elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Media_formats_supported_by_the_audio_and_video_elements).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code gives:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'play'

Note the [get()](http://api.jquery.com/get/) below in order to get the DOM object:

```
$(function () {
  $('input').click(function () {
    $('video').get(0).play();
  });
});​
```

Comment: Thank you, I did not know that about jquery objects.